# SASS overwrite not stopping

Tags: ruby, sass

I install ruby and then sass. Then type `sass`--watch ruby.scss:test.css

The format was made but also this error shows

```
"Listen has fallen back to polling" and won't watch
```

So updated to the new version **3.2.0.alpha.247** and that was gone ^_^.

But before the update and after when the file is overwrite when i save the ruby.scss file it continues to overwrite the file

```
overwrite test.css
overwrite test.css
overwrite test.css
overwrite test.css
overwrite test.css
overwrite test.css
overwrite test.css
... Infinite Loop
```

and to stop it `ctrl+c`

Any ideas how to fix this ?